# TypeError: forward() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given, ERROR Mask R CNN

Tags: python, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, vision, faster-rcnn

I am trying to implement Mask R CNN, but I am getting the error:

> TypeError: forward() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given.

Please if anybody can help me solve this I would be very grateful.
My errors look like this:

> File "/tmp/projecttutorial2/test maskrcnn hyperspectral.py", line 244, in 
>       train_one_epoch1(model, optimizer, data_loader, device, epoch, print_freq=10)
>
> File "/tmp/projecttutorial2/test maskrcnn hyperspectral.py", line 204, in train_one_epoch1
>       loss_dict = model(images, targets)
>
> File "/home/student/anaconda3/envs/deeplearning/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 532, in **call**
>       result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
>
> TypeError: forward() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

Comment: Can you provide the code used in the error snippet?

Comment: Unless we do not see what's going on in your code, we can't trace the error root. So please provide the scripts where shown.

Comment: I guess it's because you're passing two values to model() (that is defined in torch.nn.Module) in line 204 of the file test maskrcnn hyperspectral.py while you should pass only one. That is what I can deduce from the error, but without a code snippet we can't help you anymore.